# Создание объекта блокировки?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

всем привет, имеется такой пример:

```
class Program
{
    static object locker = new object();

    static void WriteSecond()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', 10) + "Secondary");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.SetWindowSize(80, 45);

        ThreadStart writeSecond = new ThreadStart(WriteSecond);
        Thread thread = new Thread(writeSecond);
        thread.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Primary");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

как видно, создается две критические секции lock, и они используют один объект блокировки в двух разных методах - одна критическая секция в методе WriteSecond, а вторая в методе Mian() , но обе эти секции все равно находятся в пределах одного класса - класса Program.
Возможно точно такое же "разделение" объекта блокировки между двумя критическими секциями, если эти секции будут находится разных классах?
Если такое возможно, то попрошу привести пример кода с разъяснением к нему, а если нет - то почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. В вашем примере объект locker (он статический) можно сделать public и использовать в любом другом классе: lock(Program.locker). Информация о блокировке "привязана" к объекту locker. Нет разницы, какой объект использует locker для блокировки.

Но так делать не очень хорошо. Обычно объекты блокировки стараются держать как можно более закрытыми, чтобы легче было отследить блокировки, когда возникнут проблемы с ними.